# Nested forms: How to correctly access a certain instance with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have an *Order*, which always has exactly two addresses: A *invoice address* and a *shipping address*. In the view, I have a form, where you can enter both addresses. From my controller I pass on the instance *@order*, with two sub instances of *addresses* already built.

Extract from my OrdersConntroller:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new(orderCreationDate: Time.now)
  2.times{ @order.addresses.build }
end
```

In the view, how can I access just the first @order.addresses, and then in some other place the second @order.addresses?

What I've tried so far:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
...
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |ff| %>
   <%= ff.text_field :firstName %> 
  ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But then the HTML result is the following (where the name and id is not right).

```
<input type="text" name="order[a][firstName]" id="order_a_firstName">
```

Extract from my *Order* model:

```
has_many :addresses, foreign_key: "orderID"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true
```

Thx for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create two model 1) InvoiceAddress and 2) ShippingAddress

```
class InvoiceAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = :address
end

class ShippingAddress < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.table_name = :address
end
```

and in order model use association as follows

```
has_one :invoice_address
has_one :shipping_address
```

and orders_controller.rb

```
def new
  @order = Order.new(orderCreationDate: Time.now)
  @invoice_address = @order.build_invoice_address
  @shipping_address = @order.build_shipping_address
end
```

form will be

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
   ...
   <%= f.fields_for :invoice_address, @invoice_address  do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_field :firstName %> 
      ...
   <% end %>
   <%= f.fields_for :shipping_address, @shipping_address  do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_field :firstName %> 
      ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I see how u tackle this problem. But what if I try to save the order and a validation on one of the addresses fails? How can I make sure that all 3 instances are only saved if all validations pass (otherwise there should be a rollback)?

Comment: validation will also work using above approach, just try it.